# How to display the schedule of movies in different cinema theaters (UWP)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

For a UWP Windows app for cinemas, I need to have an overview of movies running in different theaters. The best way to do this seems to be a calendar/timetable type of view to me, like the daily and weekly views from Google calendar (time vertically, rooms horizontally).

There doesn't seem to be an easy way in Visual Studio to accomplish a layout as such. How could I make a control or UI element like that? Or maybe there is a better solution to display the movies on a certain day?

Example of what the control could look like:
[image: Nicked from Google calendar: This is what the control could look like: rooms on the horizontal axis, time on the vertical axis, movies are in the grid.]

Next to being visible, the planned shows should also be clickable to enable editing afterward.

Comment: Your example looks more like a table than calendar. In any case, you should check out [telerik uwp tooolkit](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP), particularly Calendar and Grid section. But you right, it won't be easy to implement such layout.

Comment: I had found this toolkit aswell, but I'm not sure how to implement my idea, since it's going across cells and might start or end halfway a cell. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I might have found a solution to my problem. When searching with the term timetable (thanks for the hint Andrey. I'm not native English), I found https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/schedule. This is similar to the windows build in calendar app, which features daily view (timetable). Only problem now is to change days to theaters...